# Post a link on my Facebook wall using Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, reference

I know that this question was asked a lot of times, but still I can find deprecated solutions or solutions that mix logins and authentications (which is not needed in my case).

I was wondering which is the fastest (and smartest) way of sharing a website link on Facebook using either Java or Javascript. I just want to post the message:

```
You scored 9/10 on the game: <link>
```

I think a clear HowTo would be of great help to me and other people fighting with the same dilemma :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Thought there were some APIs useful for servlets and JSPs...

Comment: If you want solution in java then you need to have application on Facebook. You can check http://www.springsource.org/spring-social.

Answer (score 2):

You could use simple JS

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: What if I want to prefill the field with a predefined message (as the one I posted in my question) **without** having an application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `javascript` you need to include `Facebook javascript SDK` to your site. This is how you should add [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Example for adding to post to your wall.

```
function(message, name, pictures, description, link) {
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    message: message,
    name: name,
    picture: picture,
    description: description,
    link: link
  }, function (result) {
    var retVal = true;
    if (result) {
        console.log('Facebook API: Send Status: Success');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Facebook API: Send Status: Failed');
        retVal = false;
    } return retVal;
  });
}
```

This solution does not include user action it can be done in background. Only thing that is needed is that is user logged on Facebook, and you have application on Facebook.

Comment: This is the point: I don't have an application on Facebook. Still, I want to publish something on the wall, which is not related to any application.

Comment: Then you can use simple share dialog as @AB suggested.

Comment: Thanks for this, also there is a typo, you have consol instead of console